# Incorrect seconds difference between two TimeSpan

Tags: datetime, xamarin, timespan

I am trying to find the difference in two timestamps, in one of my project.
I have a timestamp on which touches on the screen and I subtract it from `DateTime.Now`

Here is how I am doing it-

`var sec = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(TimeOfUserTouch)`
`TimeOfUserTouch` is also a `TimeSpan` object.

`Console.WriteLine("Time Now {0} \n\n Earlier Time {1} \n\n Difference {2}",DateTime.Now, TimeOfUserTouch, sec.Seconds);`

When I printed the output, here is how it shows-

> Time Now: 12/8/2020 4:38:46 PM
> Earlier Time: 12/8/2020 4:37:56 PM
> Difference: 14 sec

Now this difference is clearly wrong. Ideally it should return 50 sec.
Could you guys explain what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: please post the relevant code you are using to generate that output

Comment: @Jason - Please check now, have added the the `WriteLine` statement used to print the output.

Comment: there is TotalSeconds property use it instead of Seconds

Comment: this works fine for me - note that you are calling DateTime.Now multiple times, instead call it once and save the result so you are using a consistent value in your calcs

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan - Using `TotalSeconds` fixed the problem. 
Is it possible for you to please explain what exactly is the behavioural difference in `Seconds` and `TotalSeconds`?  why was it returning incorrect difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else runs into the same problem -
I ended up using using `TotalSeconds` instead of `seconds`as suggested by @Gevorg in the comment, which fixed the issue.